# How to show different text on iOS and Android in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to place a FAQ in my flutter app and tried to run through the docs but is unsure how to use the "Platform.isAndroid" and "Platform.isiOS" to display different flutter texts for different platform.

Source: https://docs.flutter.dev/resources/platform-adaptations

```
ListTile(
    title: Text('1. What is a question?'),
    subtitle: Text('This is the first answer to Android. || This is the second answer to iOS.'),
),
```

Any guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few mingling around, I found this solution.

```
 ListTile(
            title: Text('1. What is a question?'),
            subtitle: Text(Platform.isAndroid
                ? 'This is the answer for Android.'
                : (Platform.isIOS
                    ? 'This is the answer for iOS.'
                    : 'This is the default answer for other platforms.')),
          ),
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it's not as easily extensible to other alternatives (e.g. web or Windows).  Even if Android and IOS are the only two platforms you're interested in today ... it's always a good idea to consider what you might want (or *NEED*!) *tomorrow*.  IMHO...

Comment: My answer does contain an approach for other platforms apart from Android and iOS

Comment: Only if you nest your ternary operators.  Which doesn't scale well. - you need another level of nesting for each additional platform. STRONG SUGGESTION: this is a great use case for a private method, e.g. `subtitle: getTitle(),`; .  "getTitle()" will have an if/else or case block that returns the desired text.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just declare a text variable, and use [Platform](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-platform_platform/Platform-class.html), with an if/else block (or switch/case block) to assign it's value?

```
if (Platform.isIOS) { 
    myText = "ABC";
} else if (Platform.isAndroid) { 
    myText = "DEF";
} else {
    ...
}
```